# How to load .pages documents in UIWebView iOS 7?

Tags: objective-c, ios7, webview, uiwebview

I have problems with loading .pages documents in iOS 7. I tried with this code

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:str  ofType:@"pages" inDirectory:@""];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webview loadRequest:request];
```

Then I tried with

```
-(void)loadDocument:(NSString*)documentName inView:(UIWebView*)webView
{
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:documentName ofType:nil];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [webView loadRequest:request];
}

// Calling -loadDocument:inView:
[self loadDocument:@"mydocument.rtfd.zip" inView:self.myWebview];
```

But I want to load more than 50 .pages documents in collection view and I get this error :

> warning: failed to set breakpoint site at 0x11428984c for breakpoint 1.1: Unable to read memory at breakpoint address.